# Is it acceptable to post one homework question with answer and ask for more solutions

Tags: discussion

For example, I post one question, and I have one solution.
Which is better?
My solution in the answer or in the question post? I also need some verification.

My purposes are : get hints(if unsolvable by myself), expect for more possible solutions, verified my solution.

Because I know homework question seems be not acceptable when one directly post it and ask for one full and detailed solution, unless the question is challenging or interesting or....

Of course homework is not real homework for me.
I just wanna see more solutions, and more related materials, and more ...

Answer (score 3):

> I also need some verification.

If I read this correctly, it means that your question is in part about the correctness of the solution that you have. If so, then the purported solution should be a part of the question, since it is something you are asking about. And even if you are confident in the solution and just want to know if there are better ones, the solution should still be a part of the question, because one has to read it to know what "better" means.

There are other considerations:

- Subscribers of RSS feeds such as `newest questions` will see your question but not the answer you posted to it.
- Those who filter for questions without answers will not see a question to which an answer is posted at once.

If the solution is found to be correct, and no better ones were offered, you may want to move it from the question to an answer, and accept that answer.

> I just wanna see more solutions, and more related materials, and more ...

No problem, as long as you manage to keep the question focused (otherwise it may be found to be *too broad*). For example, "I want to see more materials related to evaluation of integrals" would probably be too broad.

Comment: The tags ([tag:solution-verification]) and ([tag:alternative-proof]) may be useful.

Comment: @Lord_Farin ah, good to know the `alternative-proof` tag.

Comment: After seeing your answer, I think it's good to include my solution in question post when wanna see some alternative solutions.